# How to access the Java method in a C++ application

Tags: java, c++, c

Just a simple question:
Is it possible to call a java function from c/c++ ?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Yes you can, but it is a little convoluted, and works in a reflective/non type safe way (example uses the C++ api which is a little cleaner than the C version).  In this case it creates an instance of the Java VM from within the C code.  If your native code is first being called from Java then there is no need to construct a VM instance

```
#include<jni.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    JavaVM *vm;
    JNIEnv *env;
    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
    vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_2;
    vm_args.nOptions = 0;
    vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = 1;

    // Construct a VM
    jint res = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&vm, (void **)&env, &vm_args);

    // Construct a String
    jstring jstr = env->NewStringUTF("Hello World");

    // First get the class that contains the method you need to call
    jclass clazz = env->FindClass("java/lang/String");

    // Get the method that you want to call
    jmethodID to_lower = env->GetMethodID(clazz, "toLowerCase",
                                      "()Ljava/lang/String;");
    // Call the method on the object
    jobject result = env->CallObjectMethod(jstr, to_lower);

    // Get a C-style string
    const char* str = env->GetStringUTFChars((jstring) result, NULL);

    printf("%s\n", str);

    // Clean up
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(jstr, str);

    // Shutdown the VM.
    vm->DestroyJavaVM();
}
```

To compile (on Ubuntu):

```
g++ -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/include \ 
    -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/include/linux \ 
    -L/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre/lib/i386/server/ -ljvm jnitest.cc
```

Note: that the return code from each of these methods should be checked in order to implement correct error handling (I've ignored this for convenience).  E.g.

```
str = env->GetStringUTFChars(jstr, NULL);
if (str == NULL) {
    return; /* out of memory */
}
```

Comment: +1 for example. Might also want to include links/examples of setting up the headers, function signatures, etc?

Comment: your solution is great but what how to load or set classpath that we created For example HelloWorld.java i.e `env->FindClass("HelloWorld");`

Comment: This worked for me, thank goodness. I upvoted, and let me just mention that I used "-Wl,-rpath,${lib_dir}", without quotes of course, where lib_dir is the directory where libjvm.so lies (I used 'find /usr/lib/jvm/ -name "libjvm.so"', and took the dirname for the actual jvm lib directory in my environment). The -Wl,-rpath,${lib_dir} in the link (or compile/link) step (i.e. g++) makes it so you don't have to specify lib_dir in LD_LIBRARY_PATH at runtime.

Answer (score 11):

Yes it is, but you have to do it via JNI: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/index.html

Comment: I've seen JNI used to call C++ from Java. Didn't know it worked the other way as well.

Comment: Strange, I've always seen it more commonly used to provide access to C++ libraries from Java, but it works both ways.

Comment: @CBBailey "provide access to C++ libraries from Java" means "call C++ from Java". No? I feel like you're both saying the same thing: "Commonly used to call [C++ code] from Java".

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the [invocation API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html). This enables you to load and start up a JVM from *within* your native application, and then to invoke methods upon it from the application.

Briefly (from the linked doc)

```
/* load and initialize a Java VM, return a JNI interface  
 * pointer in env */ 
JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, &env, &vm_args); 

/* invoke the Main.test method using the JNI */ 
jclass cls = env->FindClass("Main"); 
jmethodID mid = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls, "test", "(I)V"); 
env->CallStaticVoidMethod(cls, mid, 100);
```

Comment: The link in this answer is broken.

Comment: Now amended the link

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways. [Here](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t145474-how-to-call-java-from-c.html) are some ideas. In addition, commercial Java-COM bridges allow COM communication from c++ to java (if you are using Windows). You should also look at [CNI](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcj/Invocation.html).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can call a Java function from C++ or C, but unless you're using something like COM or CORBA (or another 3rd-party tool that I'm probably not aware of) you'll have to do this in the context of JNI.

The whole procedure to call a Java method from native code is described in Chapter 4 in section 4.2 called "Calling Methods" in Sun's JNI guide pdf, which you can find [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html).

Answer (score 2):

The following function allows you to create the VM.

```
JNIEnv* create_vm(JavaVM ** jvm)
{
    JNIEnv *env;
    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
    JavaVMOption options[2];

    options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=.";
    options[1].optionString = "-DXcheck:jni:pedantic";  

    vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
    vm_args.nOptions = 2;
    vm_args.options = options;
    vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_TRUE; // remove unrecognized options

    int ret = JNI_CreateJavaVM(jvm, (void**) &env, &vm_args);
    if (ret < 0) printf("\n<<<<< Unable to Launch JVM >>>>>\n");
    return env;
}
```

Compile the famous [Hello World](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11hello/HelloWorld.java.html) program. The following function attempts to call the main method of the HelloWorld Program.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    JNIEnv* env;
    JavaVM* jvm;

    env = create_vm(&jvm);

    if (env == NULL) return 1;

    jclass myClass = NULL;
    jmethodID main = NULL;


    myClass = env->FindClass("HelloWorld");


    if (myClass != NULL)
        main = env->GetStaticMethodID(myClass, "main", "([Ljava/lang/String;)V");
    else
        printf("Unable to find the requested class\n");


    if (main != NULL)
    {
       env->CallStaticVoidMethod( myClass, main, " ");

    }else printf("main method not found") ;


    jvm->DestroyJavaVM();
    return 0;
}
```

Now put create_vm function and main function into a single cpp file, include jni.h and compile it. I used MinGW on windows.

```
g++ -D_JNI_IMPLEMENTATION_ -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_32\include" -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_32\include\win32" hello.cpp -L"C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\client" -ljvm -o hello.exe
```

**Exection**
Now if you run the created exe, you will get an error. [jvm.dll not found](http://wikis.openlinksw.com/UdaWikiWeb/JvmDllNotFound) .
Put `C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\client` in your PATH environment variable. Now you can 
run the exe file.

Note: Don't displace the jvm.dll file.

Answer (score 0):

After coding above examples, you need to do some configuration on your project.

Steps to link the jvm.lib to your project in Visual Studio:

- Right click on the project -> properties.
- On the Properties dialog box, add jvm.lib under Linker->Input->AdditionalDependencies area.
- Lastly write jvm.lib path(like "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\lib") under 
  Linker->General->AdditionalLibraryDirectories

After those steps, your project can link to jvm and work well.