# Use JAR file in c++/c

Tags: java, c++, c, invocation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to access the Java method in a C++ application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992836/how-to-access-the-java-method-in-a-c-application)

I need to use JAR file in c++ program. i.e. from c++ i need to call java function, for example, 
    In java there is a function who accept 2 integer and return addition of that, Now i need to call this function from c++.
Please guide me
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use the *Java Invocation API*, described [here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/invocation.html#wp9502) This example code (from that link) shows how to load in a Java Virtual Machine and use it to call a static Java method named `test` with an `int` argument, located in the class `Main`. In this example, the path to the JAR file would be set using the `vm_args.classpath` variable.

```
#include <jni.h>       /* where everything is defined */
...
JavaVM *jvm;       /* denotes a Java VM */
JNIEnv *env;       /* pointer to native method interface */
JDK1_1InitArgs vm_args; /* JDK 1.1 VM initialization arguments */
vm_args.version = 0x00010001; /* New in 1.1.2: VM version */
/* Get the default initialization arguments and set the class 
 * path */
JNI_GetDefaultJavaVMInitArgs(&vm_args);
vm_args.classpath = ...;
/* load and initialize a Java VM, return a JNI interface 
 * pointer in env */
JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, &env, &vm_args);
/* invoke the Main.test method using the JNI */
jclass cls = env->FindClass("Main");
jmethodID mid = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls, "test", "(I)V");
env->CallStaticVoidMethod(cls, mid, 100);
/* We are done. */
jvm->DestroyJavaVM();
```

If you wanted to call a non-static method, the code would be only slightly different, and the rest of the [Java Native Interface tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/jniTOC.html) explains all you need to know.

Comment: HI, here we are using java class, but i need to include jar file

Comment: As I said, set the `vm_args.classpath` variable to the path to the jar file -- i.e., "./libs/thejarfile.jar". The JVM will find the class inside the jar file. If you need to include more than one jar file, then this same variable should be a colon (UNIX) or semicolon (WINDOW) -separated list of jar file paths.