# call Scala code from C / C++

Tags: c++, c, scala, interop

If I have a .jar file with a compiled scala method, is there any way to call it from a C/C++ dll ? How can I do this? I have only been able to find infos on the opposite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Scala program (once compiled) is a Java class. So follow this suggestion: [How to access the Java method in a C++ application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992836/how-to-access-the-java-method-in-a-c-application)