# Where can I programmatically get background color of IntelliJ IDEA code editor?

Tags: intellij-idea, color-scheme

I want to copy some colors from IntelliJ color scheme to my application color scheme automatically. Where can I find for example code editor background color of IntelliJ IDEA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find it [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/editor-ui-ex/src/com/intellij/openapi/editor/colors/impl/AbstractColorsScheme.java#L132), for example.

[This](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/editor-ui-api/src/com/intellij/openapi/editor/HighlighterColors.java#L22) is a file with the definition of Text colours.

Also check out [this](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/editor-ui-api/src/com/intellij/openapi/editor/colors/EditorColors.java) file. It defines many system colours. (like caret, gutter, selection, etc.)

Comment: This is part of the Java API, so I'm not quite sure about that.

Comment: If you like the answer and do not have any additional questions, you can accept it (green button on the left) or upvote it.

Comment: Sorry, I delete the comment.
The comment was:
"Is it possible to call this API from C++ (for example from Qt)"
I think I get an answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992836/how-to-access-the-java-method-in-a-c-application