# Getting colors from current user selected theme

Tags: intellij-plugin

I started making an IntelliJ plugin in Java and wanted to know if there is a way to programmatically get certain colors from
the current IDE theme, for example getting the magenta terminal foreground color.

For now I only achieve getting a light color for light theme and dark for dark.

What I aim to is to get precise colors from the user installed color schemes. For instance I use the `Atom One Dark` theme from the plugin store.

I'm looking to get the colors in the currently selected ColorScheme, all colors from themes are stored into an `.icls` file by the format :

```
<option name="CONSOLE_ERROR_OUTPUT">
   <value>
      <option name="FOREGROUND" value="e06c75" />
   </value>
</option>
```

I'd like to get the color by its `name` attribute.

Thanks for helping, have a nice day.

Comment: Here you can find some classes from intelij openapi:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55576830/13523946

Comment: These show me the composition of the ColorSchemes, however i'm looking for the currently selected ColorScheme by the user in the `Appearance -> Theme` dropdown menu in settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you very much you both lead me in the right direction !
I found just what I was looking for.
You can get my function for collecting color schemes colors at the bottom of this post.

### The solution was :

ColorSchemes files or `.icls` files look like this :

```
<scheme name="ThemeName" version="142" parent_scheme="Darcula">
  <metaInfo>
  </metaInfo>
  <colors>
    <option name="ADDED_LINES_COLOR" value="98c379" />
  </colors>
  <attributes>
    <option name="ABSTRACT_CLASS_NAME_ATTRIBUTES">
      <value>
        <option name="FOREGROUND" value="e6c07b" />
      </value>
    </option>
  </attributes>
</scheme>
```

You can get those colors programmatically , in java (sorry I don't know how to do it in Kotlin) you can fetch the current color scheme by doing :

```
EditorColorsScheme colorsScheme = EditorColorsManager.getInstance().getSchemeForCurrentUITheme();
```

Or you can get the default color scheme by doing :

```
EditorColorsScheme colorsScheme = = EditorColorsManager.getInstance().getScheme(EditorColorsManager.getInstance().getAllSchemes()[0].getName());
```

From that I've made a simple function that can fetch a specific color by its name (attribute and colors). If the name given does not correspond to a color defined in *<attributes>* it will look in the *<colors>* section. You can also precise if you specifically want the background color of an attribute.

### Here is the function :

```
public Color fetchIJColor(String name, boolean isBackground){
    Color c = colorsScheme.getAttributes(TextAttributesKey.createTextAttributesKey(name)).getForegroundColor();
    if(c == null || isBackground){
        c = colorsScheme.getAttributes(TextAttributesKey.createTextAttributesKey(name)).getBackgroundColor();
    }
    if(c == null){
        c = colorsScheme.getColor(ColorKey.createColorKey(name));
    }
    return c;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can check class: UIUtil for example UIUtil.getTreeTextBackground() it should return Color

Comment: Thanks ! This is working for me to get the Background colors correctly ! However i'm looking to get some colors appearing in the editor too. For instance the color of a string surrounded by `"`. I figured that the Color i'm looking for is stored in ColorScheme `icls` files and looks like this for a given color : ```<option name="CONSOLE_ERROR_OUTPUT"><value><option name="FOREGROUND" value="e06c75" /></value></option>```