# Is it possible for a C++ class to inherit from a Java class through JNI?

Tags: java, c++

I have the following Java class:

```
public class Dog {

    public void bark() {
        System.out.println("Aw");
    }
}
```

Is it possible to write a C++ class, say Poodle, which inherits from Dog and overrides the Java bark method?

**EDIT1:** The big challenge here is that the Poodle C++ class will have to be executed by an embedded JVM created with `JNI_CreateJavaVM` **O.o**

**EDIT2:** Unfortunately this looks impossible :( => But for part 2 of this question you can check here: [Is it possible for a C++ program to receive Java method calls from an embedded JVM running through JNI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71985100/is-it-possible-for-a-c-program-to-receive-java-method-calls-from-an-embedded-j)

Comment: It is possible to [call Java methods from C++ classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992836/how-to-access-the-java-method-in-a-c-application), so you could define a C++ class that invokes methods from the Java class.

Comment: Thanks @AndersonGreen. But I don't think that would work. I would like to override a Java method in C++, not call a Java method from C++.

Comment: I wouldn't expect it.   The Java object model supports class introspection (e.g. a class hierarchy can be interrogated at run time) which the C++ object model does not  (e.g. all relationships are specified at compile time).   Having a C++ class derived from something that is not known until runtime (including deriving a C++ class from a Java class) conflicts with the C++ object model.   I suppose it might be notionally possible with a C++ compiler that targets a specific JVM platform - but such a solution would be specific to that compiler and that JVM.

Comment: Great answer, @Peter. This should be impossible :( Do you mind checking this now => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71985100/is-it-possible-for-a-c-program-to-receive-java-method-calls-from-an-embedded-j